# What are the valid Java @WebMethod return types?

Tags: java, web-services, webmethod

I am writing a WebService using Java. Now I have a @WebMethod that is supposed to return some data, and I am not sure what format to use. I have seen that in other languages, there are certain restrictions on @WebMethod return types - is this the same for Java?

When I tried to return a DOM Document containing XML, I got an error saying "Unable to create JAXBContext", so I changed it to just returning a String array. However, getting content from that array is rather tedious. Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks,

VeganSmarties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was implementing JAX-WS web services, all my return types were annotated with JAXB annotations (@XmlElement, ...), and they also were Serializable. EDIT: which means just any type will not work, and you will have to create wrappers around structures you want to return.

Comment: Thanks - So you created your own objects, made them Serializable, annotated them and then returned them? So not all WebMethod return types have to be in XML, but they can..?

Comment: JAX-WS is Java API for XML Web Services, which means both input/output are XML under the hood. However, afair primitives & they according wrappers + arrays of those are handled automatically (your case when you turned return into String array).

Comment: Ok! Thanks - that makes sense! :) One last question - when I return a String[][] array like {[a,b],[b,c],[c,d]} the xml uses <item> tags for everything, so it looks like: <item> <item> a </item> <item> b </item> </item> <item> <item> b </item> etc... How can I change the tag names to more meaningful data, say <word> <letter> or something?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's element to specify element name for array-based items (but there could be!), so I recommend you reading about JAXB annotations (e.g., start with JavaDoc - annotations package: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html); but you can always create wrapper-class which is easy, specify it's element name; and also use @XmlElementWrapper for 'container element' name.

Comment: @WebResult works for single Strings, I just found out, but I will try to find a solution for the array as well. Thank you again for your help!